# Check pin capabilities at compile time

Tags: interrupt, pins, analogread, analogwrite, digitalwrite

Are there board-independent functions to check pin capabilities at compile time? I.e.

- Can the pin be used as output, as in `digitalWrite()`?
- Does the pin support PWM, as in `analogWrite()`?
- Does the pin support ADC, as in `analogRead()`?
- Does the pin support interrupts, as in `attachInterrupt()`?

I'm looking for functions/macros like e.g. `isDigitalOutput(pin)` which would return false for input-only pins such as A6 and A7 on a 328P, but true on a Mega where those pins are input/output.

Comment: I'm afraid not, Its best to look up documentation or schematics for the board, if you would like to do it by yourself, you can set any pin to any of the states and test whether it works properly, and take some notes

Comment: @Coder9390 I wanted to do a check in a library function which requires an analog pin, but I think I'll just drop the idea. No way I'm going to look up every analog pin on every possible board.

Comment: maybe a check for a definition of `A0` would work

Comment: Firmata contains a large list of pin definitions for boards. The official version https://github.com/firmata/ConfigurableFirmata/blob/master/src/utility/Boards.h is a bit outdated, but the most common Arduinos are included

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/9f8d27f09f3bbd1da1374b5549a82bda55d45d44/variants/mega/pins_arduino.h#L27

Answer (score 1):

For compatibility with `analogWrite()` there's `digitalPinHasPWM(p)` macro which returns 1 when PWM is supported on pin `p`.

For `analogRead()` there's `analogInputToDigitalPin()` which can be used as

```
#if ((p-PIN_A0 < 0) || (analogInputToDigitalPin(p-PIN_A0) != p))
#error Not an analog pin!
#endif
```

For `attachInterrupt()` there is `digitalPinToInterrupt(p)` which returns `NOT_AN_INTERRUPT` if the pin `p` doesn't support interrupts.

I still haven't found anything to test compatibility with `digitalWrite()`.

Comment: you asked about compile time

Comment: @Juraj Right, `A0` is not a macro (`PIN_A0` must be used instead).

Comment: but the answer is about runtime

Comment: @Juraj No, all of the above checks are macros.

Comment: sorry, I see. after edit it is a macro